# How upload text file in Vaadin to textField?

Tags: upload, vaadin

I know how upload and save file. But how to upload the file without saving on disk and display text-data in TextArea or TextField.

Comment: can you show your code? is it not a possibility to upload, read then delete?

Comment: Yeah, I can do that, but I don't know how do it without saving.

Comment: is there a reason you can't save? can you show your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the vaadin upload you should be able to use a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) instead of a FileOutputStream.

So just use the sample from the [book of vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.upload.html) but use a ByteArrayOuputStream instead.

When the uploadSucceeded method is called, you take the ByteArrayOutputStream, convert it into a string (Beware of the correct encoding) and set it as the value of your TextArea/Field.